# InvalidOperationException (sequence containing no elements

Tags: c#, winforms, invalidoperationexception

```
            List<Invaders> invadersShooting = new List<Invaders>();
        Invaders invaderA=new Invaders();
    try
            {
        var invaderByLocationX = from invadersSortByLocation in invaders
                                 group invadersSortByLocation by invadersSortByLocation.Location.Y
                                 into invaderGroup
                                 orderby invaderGroup.Key
                                 select invaderGroup;

        if (invaderByLocationX != null)
        {

                invadersShooting = invaderByLocationX.Last().ToList();// it is being throwing constantly here.. How can i prevent it from being thrown

                invaderA = invadersShooting[r.Next(0, invadersShooting.Count)];




                if (r.Next(5) < 4 - randomShot)
                {
                    Invadershots.Add(new Shot(invaderA.Location, Direction.DOWN, gameBoundaries, WEAPON.DEFAULT, isWeapon));
                }
        }
            }
    catch (Exception e)
    { }
    }
```

How can i prevent the error from happening? how can i make the program check that invaderByLocationX is empty? cause it is empty, therefore the exception is thrown :(

Comment: One thing that you can do is set a breakpoint next to "var invaderByLocationX" in Visual Studio. It helps to know what's going on in your code if your application is running in debug mode.

Comment: i know what is happening. it is empty.. and i need to prevent the Last() method to be applied if it is empty!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `LastOrDefault` which will return null if the sequence is empty.  You'll then want to check for null.

```
var invader = invaderByLocationX.LastOrDefault();
if(invader == null)
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    invaderA = invadersShooting[r.Next(0, invadersShooting.Count)];
    // etc
}
```

Also note that invaderByLocationX can never be null, so the null check in unecessary.